# Haystack Django Elasticsearch spelling

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have two problems setting up haystack/django/elasticsearch

1. I never get results from index fields, e.g. indexes.CharField(model_attr='title') doesn't get me results. Only if I put {{ object.title }} in my txt template I get results for matching titles
2. If my title is 'foo' I never get results for 'fo', while I do have the INCLUDE_SPELLING setting set to True in my backend setting.

The documentation doesn't state anything special about these cases, my setup is per the haystack documentation, what am I missing?

My index:

```
class FooIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')  # never gets me results unless I add it to the template

    def get_model(self):
        return Foo
```

My settings:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have `use_template=True` only index what you put in the `template` file so put all the fields you want indexed in there.
2) Did you refresh the index after adding `INCLUDE_SPELLING` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enabled spellcheck component.

The first thing to do is create a special field on your SearchIndex class that mirrors the text field, but uses FacetCharField. This disables the post-processing that Solr does, which can mess up your suggestions. Something like the following is suggested:

```
class MySearchIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    # ... normal fields then...
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

def prepare(self, obj):
    prepared_data = super(MySearchIndex, self).prepare(obj)
    prepared_data['suggestions'] = prepared_data['text']
    return prepared_data
```

Once this is done, spelling_suggestions method should return the appropriate values.